# Pending Intent and Alarm Manager

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I have been making an Android app lately..
In it I have used Pending Intent, with Alarm Manager. 
I need to have multiple pending intents, and so I am using FLAG_ONE_SHOT. Alarm Manager will send broadcast at mentioned interval. And also, along with that I am using intent's setAction() method and passing currentTimeMillis() as Argument. And I have corresponding Broadcast Receiver. The problem is that once the app is closed, or deleted from the recents tray, the Broadcast receiver is not running. 
The code is as follow:

1. setAlarm:

   ```
   private void setupAlarm(int seconds) {
   AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
   Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), OnAlarmReceive.class);
   //PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
   intent.setAction(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));
   intent.putExtra("id", ID);

   PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ChatActivity.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

   Log.e(TAG, "Setup the Alarm");

   Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
   calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, seconds);

   alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);}
   ```
2. Broadcast Receiver

   ```
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

   String id = intent.getStringExtra("id");
   Log.e(TAG,"On the verge of deleting the message with id: "+id);
   SQLiteDatabase database = context.openOrCreateDatabase("/sdcard/userlists.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
   database.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + "MESSAGE" + " WHERE " + "id" + "= '" + id + "'");

   broadcaster = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context);
   intent = new Intent(COPA_RESULT);
   broadcaster.sendBroadcast(intent);}
   ```
3. Manifest.xml

   ```
   <receiver android:name=".OnAlarmReceive" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true"/>
   ```

Please help me. I need the Broadcaster to do the job, even if the app is closed.

Comment: use `service`.!

Comment: So, without using service, I can't receive the Broadcasts? 
If so, Can you provide the steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's *process life-cycle* bug in which **system may kill process when app goes in background to reclaim memory**

You need to schedule [JobService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobService.html) for *receiving job* whether application is active or not

from official [document](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/processes/process-lifecycle.html) of Processes and Application Life Cycle

> A common example of a process life-cycle bug is a BroadcastReceiver
>   that starts a thread when it receives an Intent in its
>   BroadcastReceiver.onReceive() method, and then returns from the
>   function. Once it returns, the system considers the BroadcastReceiver
>   to be no longer active, and thus, its hosting process no longer needed
>   (unless other application components are active in it). So, the system
>   may kill the process at any time to reclaim memory, and in doing so,
>   it terminates the spawned thread running in the process. The solution
>   to this problem is typically to schedule a JobService from the
>   BroadcastReceiver, so the system knows that there is still active work
>   being done in the process.

Here is [example](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTaskScheduling/article.html) you can follow to complete your requirement

Comment: have you understood?

Comment: Yes... Very very sorry for the late reply... But thank you very much!

Comment: @KishoreJethava can you elaborate more on it?